# How to append an array to an array at current index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array `myarray` and I am using a for loop to get a few information which I add to `myarray`. But next time the `for`-loop runs, I don't want to create a separate index, but instead the 2nd time and so on, I want to append the information to `myarray[0]`.

How do I do that?

```
var myarray = [String]()

for var j in 0 < 12 {
    // do some stuff
    for var i in 0 ..< 10 {
        let parta = json?["users"][j]["name"].string
        let partb = json?["users"][j]["Lname"].string
        let partc = json?["users"][j]["dob"].string

        myarray.append("\(parta)-\(partb)-\(partc)---")
        // Here when the for loop comes back again (i = 1) , i dont want to make
        // myarray[1] ,  but instead i want myarray[0] ,
        // having value like [parta-partb-partc--parta-partb-partc]
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, append the new name/lname/dob values at `myarray[0]` without affecting the current value/string at `myarray[0]`.

Comment: Just assign the value at 0 index like this :- myarray[0] = json?["name"].string

Comment: Actually you are going to build a single string rather than an array.

Comment: @MandeepSingh and then how would i put Lname and dob at myarray[0] ??

I am trying to make a long string that shows name,lastname,dob of several people. (In a single string) And then put it at myarray[0] , then similarly get another very long string and put it at myarray[1](with the help of another forloop)

Comment: `myarray.insert("\(parta)-\(partb)-\(partc)---", at: 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create one long string and add the new data always at the beginning of the string. One way to do that would be:

```swift
// Store somewhere
var myString = String()

for var i in(0..<10) {

    let parta = json?["name"].string
    let partb = json?["Lname"].string
    let partc = json?["dob"].string

    let newString = "\(parta)-\(partb)-\(partc)---")
    newString.append(myString)
    myString = newString
    // Here when the for loop comes back again (i = 1) , i dont want to make 
    //myarray[1] ,  but instead i want myarray[0] , 
    //having value like [parta-partb-partc--parta-partb-partc]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert single element and also add array as below.

**Swift 5**

```
var myarray = [String]()
myarray.insert("NewElement", at: 0)
myarray.insert(contentsOf: ["First", "Second", "Third"], at: 0)
```